# Combinatorics books for contests.

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

I've been studying combinatorics for some time from a contest-prep perspective. The books I have more-or-less gone through are *Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics* and *A Walk Through in Combinatorics* (very slightly read). What I'd like to know is that are there more books on Combinatorics with numerous problems and proper, clear explanations. I went through a book on Combinatorics by Mladenovic--Its coverage of topics was great, with Burnside Lemma, Graph Theory, etc. However, the book escalated very quickly with complex explanations for even simple solutions that I knew.

So, tl;dr: please suggest books on Combinatorics that are informal in their tone, that delve into Combinatorics deeply with a hell lotta practice problems of ALL difficulties.

I don't want to be stuck on an impossible problem, but rather learn concepts nice and easy. Also, some difficult problems every now and then would be good too.

Thanks a ton!

P.S.: I read *Combinatorics* by Vilenkin and I liked the approach through real life examples. Would like something like it. Or is it good enough for contests?

Edit: I've already checked AoPS recommendations, previously as well. All I want are your personal opinions, kindly. (Any Math Olympians here? And enthusiasts?)

Comment: I don't know, sir, I got the English Translation, I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have a look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Olympiad_books).

In this aops-link you'll find some of the best books regarding Olympiad-training categorized into **Theory**, **Problems** and **Both** books and into **Algebra, Number Theory, Geometry** and **Combinatorics** (which are the basic olympiad disciplines).

I personally haven't read all of them, however, I would recommend you to read two of the books that helped me the most when I participated in math-olympiads:

- A Course in Combinatorics - Lint and Wilson
- A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates - Andreescu, Feng

Hope it helps ;)

*Remark:* Besides, I recommend you to practice as much as you can, i.e. solve as many *Combinatorics* problems as possible. I used to believe that reading Theory-Books would be enough, but it turned out that it wasn not...

Comment: I think so too, about solving problems. The thing is, if I could have a book with relevant theory+problems. However, thanks a lot for your advice(+1). I'll wait for some more answers!

Comment: I think I'll use Path to Combinatorics, seems really good. Do you know any problem books on Combinatorics?

Comment: Well, there's [this excellent pdf](https://parvardi.com/100combo/) by Amir Hossein Parvardi

Comment: You can also work with the [IMO shortlisted Combinatorics problems](https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx?&column=year&order=desc&language=en). These might be difficult though